# why Process.WaitForExit doesn't wait?

Tags: c#, process

why Process.WaitForExit doesn't wait?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Process.GetProcessesByName("ServerAPPFileManager").Length > 0)
                {
                    Process clsProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("ServerAPPFileManager")[0];
                    Console.WriteLine(clsProcess.ProcessName);
                    clsProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ServerAPPFileManager.exe")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File Found");
                    Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ServerAPPFileManager.exe");
                    p.Start();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

it keeps looping and starting the application again and again!

**Edit:**

It worked now, It was not working because it was like this `clsProcess.WaitForExit(1000);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is wrapped in a `while(true)` loop and there are no `break`, `throw` or `return` statements within the body of the loop.  It will indeed result in an infinite loop.

If you want to exit the loop once the `WaitForExit` has finished then you need to introduce a `break` statement to do so.

```
clsProcess.WaitForExit();
break;
```

Comment: @MurHafSoz it wall block the code until the application exits. Once it exits the code will start running again

Comment: so i keep the `while(true)` and just add a `break;` ?

Comment: @MurHafSoz it depends on your intent. It's a bit unclear what exactly this program is attempting to accomplish

Comment: the application should check if "server app" is running, if it is not .. then this application should start the server app, then it loop again to check if it's running if it's true, it waits for the application to exit to start it again, but the problem that it keeps looping when the "server app" is still running.

Comment: @MurHafSoz in that case i would change the code a bit and not use a loop.  I would essentially change the order of the `if` statements around, and remove the loop. That accomplishes what you're trying here

Comment: It's my fault, i posted a correct code, my error was when i used `clsProcess.WaitForExit(1000);` instead of `clsProcess.WaitForExit();` that why it didn't wait.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `if (Process.GetProcessesByName("ServerAPPFileManager").Length > 0)` does not return false.

Comment: It doesn't return false .. and if it does, it start the application and when the loop start again it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is the way you coded it. It is waiting for exit, then in the very next if statement it starts it again. And as Jared pointed out it keeps looping with no way to break out. so it starts it, waits for it to exit, and then startsit again

Comment: i know i want it to loop, but my problem that it doesn't wait, it loops even when the application still running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are not calling WaitForExit on the Process object that you've created, but instead on a Process object returned from Process.GetProcessesByName(). Instead, try:

```
Process p = new Process(); 
// etc
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

remove it in while statement and add it in a timer.. validate if process.hasexited=true then call again your process otherwise, validate if process.responding=true then wait else force the process kill